# Laravel relationships to tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relational-database

Quite new to Laravel and learning it now for work and just wonder, why do you have to use relationships, when you can simply use?

```
$n = Name::find(2)
$a = Address::where('name_id', '=', $n['id'])->get()
```

Instead of forming a relationship in the controller and:

```
$n = Name::find(2)
$n->address
```

Is it to less complicated somehow or is it just to reduce code or what?.

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: It is to write less code and to encapsulate things... those are the main principles in OOP... Your example is not so complicated. If a user has only one address you don't even need a separate model for adresses...but imagine a relationship a Customer and Invoice... a Customer can have multiple Invoices and you want to show all invoices (with all the details) of a certain Invoice. It would require of you to write a lot of code to show them without making relationships between the models.

Comment: Hey, thanks Lewis! Indeed, the example is very very simple, just to make the point. I have a large app to write for work and just wondered but as you've explained, it's for pretty the reason I thought and makes sense. Thanks so much

Comment: I have turned my comment to an answer...so please accept it and vote up

Answer (score 0):

It is to write less code and to encapsulate things (write once and use everywhere)... those are the main principles in OOP... Your example is not so complicated. If a user has only one address you don't even need a separate model for adress, just put it in users table as an attribute...but imagine a relationship a Customer and Invoice... a Customer can have multiple Invoices and you want to show all invoices (with all the details) of a certain Invoice. It would require of you to write a lot of code to show all the details without making relationships between the models.

Answer (score 0):

İf users have one adress, you dont need to new model. Just add 'address' column in your users table;

Here is your migration;

> php artisan make:migration add_address_column_to_users_table

İf users have multiple adress, you can use one to many releationships.

Create address model and table,

> php artisan make:model Address -m

Then in your Address model, add this function;

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

And in your User model;

```
  public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
    }
```

Thats all. You can fnd more information in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)